# Одежды могут быть... пространными?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> Наш Ямамото ценит качество и предпочитает **пространные одежды**
>   чёрного или глубокого тёмно-синего цвета.

Comment: А что, "просторные" уже запретили? Или тут в смысле "простирающиеся"? Как фата, скажем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли одежда может быть пространной, но, учитывая авторский стиль, насколько я его понял, не грех такое и оставить. Тем более если уж найдены "пространное помещение" и "пространные луга".

Answer (score 1):

Хотел было уточнить, что там автор думает, но тут ссылка сходу нашлась - в десятку.

1.ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПАРОНИМОВ ПРОСТОРНЫЙ - ПРОСТРАННЫЙ
ПРОСТОРНЫЙ -
1. Расположенный на большом пространстве, занимающий большое пространство, имеющий простор, обширный.
2. Вместительный, нетесный.
3. Неплотно прилегающий, не стесняющий движений, широкий (об одежде, обуви).
ПРОСТРАННЫЙ -
1) (устар.) Простирающийся на большое пространство; обширный.
2) (перен.) Слишком длинный, подробный, многословный (о речи, письме).
2.ПРИМЕРЫ СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЙ С ПАРОНИМОМ - ПРОСТОРНЫЙ
1)просторная гладь океана
2)просторная ширь степей
3)просторные поля и пашни
4)просторные пастбища
5)просторное небо
6)просторная пещера
7)просторное место
8)просторное сооружение
9)просторное купе
10)просторное жильё
11)просторный двор
12)просторное помещение
13)просторная гостиная
14)просторная квартира
15)просторный дом
16)просторная комната
17)просторный вестибюль
18)просторный бассейн
19)просторная изба
20)просторный шкаф
21)просторная машина
22)просторные тапки
23)просторный халат
24)просторное платье

4.ПРИМЕРЫ СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЙ С ПАРОНИМОМ - ПРОСТРАННЫЙ
1)пространный парк
2)пространное поле
3)пространные земельные владения
4)пространные леса
5)пространные луга
6)пространные воды
7)пространные излияния друга
8)пространное помещение
9)пространная версия
10)пространные рассуждения
11)пространное послание
12)пространное письмо
13)пространный текст
14)пространные рассуждения
15)пространный разговор
16)пространный комментарий
(продолжение - по ссылке.)
http://www.egeteka.ru/learning/intensive_work/russian/2499/

Никак одежда "пространнной" не получается.
Мораль. Автор - жертва паронимов.